# how to iterate in all schemas and find count from all tables present in all schemas with same table name for every 5mins?

Tags: postgresql

imagine there are 5 schemas in my database and in every schema there is a common name table (ex:- table1) after every 5mins records get inserted in table1, how I can iterate in all schemas  n calculate the count of table1[i have to automate the process so i am going to write the code in function and call that function after every 5mins using crontab].

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM schema1.table1) AS schema1count, (SELECT count(*) FROM schema2.table1) AS schema2count, (SELECT count(*) FROM schema3.table1) AS schema3count, …;`

Answer (score 0):

Basically 2 options: Hard code `schema.table` and union the results. So something like:

```
create or replace function count_rows_in_each_table1()
  returns table (schema_name text, number_or_rows integer) 
  language sql 
as $$
    select 'schema1', count(*) from schema1.table1 union all 
    select 'schema2', count(*) from schema2.table1 union all
    select 'schema3', count(*) from schema3.table1 union all
    ...
    select 'scheman', count(*) from scheman.table1; 
$$;
```

The alternative being building the query dynamically from `information_scheme`.

```
create or replace function count_rows_in_each_table1()
  returns table (schema_name text, number_of_rows bigint) 
 language plpgsql
as $$
declare
     c_rows_count  cursor  is
        select table_schema::text 
          from information_schema.tables
          where table_name = 'table1';
      
    l_tbl           record; 
    l_sql_statement text = ''; 
    l_connector     text = '';
    l_base_select   text = 'select ''%s'', count(*) from %I.table1'; 

begin
 
     for l_tbl in c_rows_count
     loop  
         l_sql_statement = l_sql_statement ||
                           l_connector ||  
                           format (l_base_select, l_tbl.table_schema, l_tbl.table_schema);
         l_connector = ' union all '; 
     end loop; 

     raise notice E'Running Query: \n%', l_sql_statement; 
     return query execute l_sql_statement; 
end;
$$;
```

Which is better. With few schema and few schema add/drop, opt for the first. It is direct and easily shows what you are doing. If you add/drop schema often then opt for the second. If you have many schema, but seldom add/drop them then modify the second to generate the first, save and schedule execution of the generated query.

**NOTE:** Not tested