# can we declare cursor in declare part and give query in begin part in function

Tags: postgresql

in multiple schemas, there is a table with the same name (ex:- schema1.table1, schema2.table1, schema3.table1, and so on) and I want to iterate in all tables how should I query in PostgreSQL.

iterate_cursor CURSOR for select ac,scheme_code,resp,err,opr from **schema_name**.vault_log where extract(minute from now()-req_ts) <= '5'; my schema name should be changed through some procedure. I tried it with for loop but for loop doesn't work in declare part and we can't declare the cursor in begin part of the function.

Comment: 1) The docs have the information [Cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html.) sections *43.7.1. Declaring Cursor Variables*, *43.7.2.3. Opening a Bound Cursor* and *43.7.4. Looping through a Cursor's Result* 2) Why do you need a cursor? Why not [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to iterate in all schemas and find count from all tables present in all schemas with same table name for every 5mins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73155063/how-to-iterate-in-all-schemas-and-find-count-from-all-tables-present-in-all-sche)